# How update the node.js in plug-in HtmlToPdf to my stress situations?

Tags: linux, svn, putty, html-to-pdf

my project is using the HtmlToPdf plug.it had installed in stress situation.

we have three situations on the project,stage,stress,and dev.
I check out the plug-in from svn(somehow I do not know why the svn address is the same as stage situation).
And now I updated the code in HtmlToPdf and committed to the svn.but How I update it in the stress situation to let it work on stress situation?
we use putty and marven.usually i commit code in the project and bash the sh to deployed it to the stress,but the plug-in seems like need different way.I am confused.

this is I do:

1,check out the svn code of the htmltopdf plug-in.
2,edit the code,and committed to svn.
3,open putty and logon stress root user.then,come to the path where the plug-in is installed.
4,re-installed it.for this step,i am in the path and print

`npm install htmlToPdf`

htmlToPdf is the file name of the the plug in svn.

and then the putty come out with a lot sentences.
the first is below:

`npm WARN deprecated jade@1.11.0:  Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
/`

and i logon stress situaction , it has no difference.

and then i  tried `npm update htmlToPdf`,but still no any change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is wrong to user npm,
npm is what i just search on internet,but i do not know what it do for.(it is really important to know why before you use it).

the correct command is `svn update`